# Why wont my php function insert into database?

Tags: php, sql

So Ive been debugging this for a couple of hours and can't seem to work it out. Ive got a form that takes info into a session then from sessions it goes into a class.

form->session->class->database

Inside the class theres a function that looks like this:

```
    function lagre($kunde)
 {
    $navn = $kunde->GetNavn();
    $telefon = $kunde->GetTelefon();
    $epost = $kunde->GetEpost();
    $antall = $kunde->GetAntall();

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","Billett");
    if($db->connect_error)
    {
        die("Couldn't connect");
    }
    else {
        echo "Connected";
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO `Billett`.`Billett` (`BillettID`, `Navn`, `Telefon`, `Epost`, `Antall`) VALUES (NULL, '$navn', '$telefon', '$epost', '$antall')";

    $resultat = mysqli_query($db,$sql);

    if(!$resultat)
    {
        echo "<br> Values not inserted";
    }
    else {
        echo "<br> Values inserted";
    }   

 }
```

The problem is that the values doesn't insert into the database. I cant work out why. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't know what's wrong because you don't check for errors in your code. Never assume the code is always going to work flawlessly. Use [`mysqli_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to get a detailed error message from the database.

Comment: When i add echo mysqli_error($resultat);  nothing prints. Does that mean theres no error or just that i wont show?

Answer (score -1):

You try to write in different way

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `Billett`.`Billett` (`BillettID`, `Navn`, `Telefon`, `Epost`, `Antall`) VALUES (NULL, '".$navn."', '".$telefon."', '".$epost."', '".$antall."')";
```

Comment: *How* does this solve their problem? You should explain *why* this should solve their problem. Just changing the way they build their query shouldn't fix *anything*.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using [Autocommit](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php)? If not then you need to commit your data to the DB, otherwise your INSERT doesn't stick:

```
/* commit transaction */
if (!$mysqli->commit()) {
    print("Transaction commit failed\n");
    exit();
}
```

Example from [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.commit.php)

Comment: Unless they explicitly turn off auto-commit, and their is no indication they have, auto-commit defaults on on.